# Not able to count line number in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, line

here is my code

```
private void Allocation_Matrix_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            int Total_Row_Check;
            Total_Row_Check = getRow();
            Textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Total_Row_Check);
            if (Total_Row_Check >= Convert.ToInt32(Total_Processes.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("rows cannot exceed from total number of processess");
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        int Row = 0;
        string[] arLines;
        int i;
        arLines = Allocation_Matrix.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (i = 0; i < arLines.Length; i++)
        {
            Row++;
        }
        return Row;
    }
```

i want to update **TextBox1** as i hit ENTER in richtextbox from keyboard...but Textbox keeps show only FirstRow and shows One(1)

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx) Method?  It returns, the zero-based line number in which the character index is located.

Answer (score 0):

Is Allocation_Matrix your RichTextBox?

Note that RichTextBox.Text returns the text with line feed ("\n") for the line breaks, where most all other Windows controls use a carriage return, line feed ("\r\n").

So if you are calling Split on the string returned by the Text property, it won't contain any Evironment.NewLine.

Comment: public int getRows()
        {
            string[] arLines;
            int i;
            arLines = Allocation_Matrix.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (i = 0; i < arLines.Length; i++)
            {
                Row++;
                // RTB2.Text = arLines[i];
            }
            return Row;
        }

Answer (score 0):

try Allocation_Matrix.Text.Lines.Count() method

Comment: No such method is available:::::::

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var lineCount = richTextBox.Lines.Count();
numberLabel.Text = lineCount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail